# After attempting to create a UIWebView with a GIF in it, when webViewDidFinishLoad is called, the URL is always just about:blank. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm trying to show a UIWebView with a GIF in it, but only once the GIF has loaded.

I load the GIF as follows:

```
    self.GIFWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.GIFWebView.delegate = self;

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><img src=\"%@\"></body></html>", post.url];
    [self.GIFWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Where `post` is just an object with some properties such as the URL for the GIF.

Then in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` I show the web view:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"%f", webView.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%@", [webView.request.URL absoluteString]);
}
```

I get "0" and "about:blank" for the `NSLog`s each time, however.

Why does it not load the GIF properly?

Comment: Try providing a base URL. See if that helps. Also, you should print `webView.scrollView.contentSize.width`.

Answer (score 6):

> I get "0" and "about:blank" for the NSLogs each time, however.

Not surprising. You're telling the web view to load HTML that you're providing in a string rather than giving it a request. The URL that you're logging is the request URL, and since there's no request, there's no request URL.

> Why does it not load the GIF properly?

Possibly because you're misusing the URL object. Look at the code:

> `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><img src=\"%@\"></body></html>", post.url];`

We can't tell what type `post.url` is, but it's probably `NSURL*`. You're probably passing a NSURL into the format string, and that may not produce the result you're looking for. Try passing in a string like `[post.url absoluteString]` instead of the actual NSURL object.

Also, you might want to log the value of `html` right after you create it so that you can check the full HTML that you're sending to the web view.

**Update:** Some additional things to check:

1. Are you running the code in question on the main thread?
2. Is the thread's run loop getting time?
3. Have you tried setting a non-nil base URL?
4. If the web view's delegate has a `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method, does it return YES?
5. What happens if you use a constant string that includes the HTML you want and the hard-coded URL instead of constructing the string with `+stringWithFormat:`?
6. Is the test device connected to the network? (Sometimes it's the simplest thing that gets you.)
7. Does it work correctly if you use a different image? I notice that the URL you're using is for an animated .gif file, try a non-animated .gif or a .jpg image instead.

**Update 2:** The problem lies in your creation of the web view. Look at the very first line in the code that you showed:

```
self.GIFWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
```

That *looks* okay for a typical object, but `-init` is not the designated initializer for a view. You should use `-initWithFrame:` instead. The image loads fine in your sample project when I change the code in your project to use the right initializer:

```
UIWebView *GIFWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: UIWebViews are sensitive about their input – if it's invalid, it won't load it, so definitely check the finished HTML string.

Comment: `post.url` returns an NSString, as `post` is just a Core Data object and url is one of its attributes. And the logged HTML is this, for example: `<html><head></head><body><img src="http://i.imgur.com/m9CiIe4.gif"></body></html>`

Comment: To allow for proper formatting I've answered your questions here: https://gist.github.com/christianselig/a2859a940790197442e9 Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @DougSmith See my second update for a solution that works in your sample project.

Comment: @Caleb My issue with that is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529872/how-to-show-a-gif-on-ios-in-a-certain-frame-not-show-it-until-fully-loaded-and). If I give it a frame originally how do I size the frame of the web view to only be the size of the GIF?

Comment: @DougSmith You can change the size of the frame later if you want.  It's possible that it'll even work if you pass `CGRectZero` for the frame -- try it and see. But clearly, initializing with `-initWithFrame:` instead of `-init` solves the problem.