# Display animated GIF from online source in IOS7

Tags: ios7, animated-gif

does anybody know any library or tools to show a animated gif which comes from a changing URL on IOS7 devices?
I'm searching for a better performance solution than UIWebView.

Maybe some code which explodes the frames into separate images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several open source projects for displaying GIFs in iOS.

Check these out:

- **[UIImage from animated GIF](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/)**
- **[GIF UIImageView Loader](https://gist.github.com/andrei512/3894888)**
- **[GIF iOS](https://github.com/piinecone/gif-ios)**
- **[Animated GIF iPhone](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone)**
- **[Flipboard FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)**

---

Also, there are questions on SO with a similar problem. Check them out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529872/how-to-show-a-gif-on-ios-in-a-certain-frame-not-show-it-until-fully-loaded-and).

Comment: I already searched for that as well. But none of these solutions work well for me. The most are using local gif files and not from online resources.

Comment: Check out the second library, it has this method +(void)loadGIFFrom:(NSString *)url to:(UIImageView *)imageView; which accepts a url. I did not personally check it out, could you give it a shot?

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you!! This is exactly what I was searching for!! 
I tried to find something for ages!

Comment: I'd add https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage as a performant open source animated GIF engine for iOS to the list.

Comment: Thanks, @RaphaelSchaad! Added that repo to my answer.